# Convert a list to dictionary in Python based on first index of list value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list something like below:

```
['C01234' , 'pass' , 'pass' , 'C2456' , 'fail' , 'pass' , 'C53675' , 'pass' , 'pass']
```

Need the output as dictionary in below format

```
{'C01234':'pass' , 'pass'}

{'C2456' : 'fail' , 'pass', 'pass'}

{'C53675': 'pass' , 'pass'}
```

can someone help?

Comment: Your desired output is invalid Python syntax

Comment: Is it a fixed number of 'pass' and 'fail'? What have you tried?

Comment: Where is the third `'pass'` for `'C2456'` coming from?

Comment: You are mixing `dict` and `list`, this is not possible using Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
data = ['C01234' , 'pass' , 'pass' , 'C2456' , 'fail' , 'pass' , 'C53675' , 'pass' , 'pass']
od = {} # Output dictionary.
key = None
for x in data:
  if x.startswith("C"):
    key = x
    od[key] = []
  elif key is not None:
    od[key].append(x)
```

This generates:

```
{'C53675': ['pass', 'pass'], 'C2456': ['fail', 'pass'], 'C01234': ['pass', 'pass']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output should be a dictionary of lists (or tuples if preferred), i.e.:

```
{'C01234': ['pass' , 'pass'],
 'C2456' : ['fail , 'pass'],
 'C53675': ['pass' , 'pass']}
```

A [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists is one way to produce this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = ['C01234', 'pass', 'pass', 'C2456', 'fail', 'pass', 'C53675', 'pass', 'pass']

values = {'pass', 'fail'}    # add any others to this set
d = defaultdict(list)
key = None
for s in l:
    if s not in values:
        key = s
    else:
        d[key].append(s)

>>> print(d)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'C53675': ['pass', 'pass'], 'C2456': ['fail', 'pass'], 'C01234': ['pass', 'pass']})
>>> print(dict(d))    # convert to a standard dictionary
{'C53675': ['pass', 'pass'], 'C2456': ['fail', 'pass'], 'C01234': ['pass', 'pass']}
```

This assumes that the values can only be one of `pass` or `fail`. You can add other values if required by adding them to the `values` set.

---

If there is always 2 values for each key then an alternative is to use a dictionary comprehension with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=zip#zip) and [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=iter#iter):

```
l = ['C01234', 'pass', 'pass', 'C2456', 'fail', 'pass', 'C53675', 'pass', 'pass']
it = iter(l)
d = {t[0]:t[1:] for t in zip(it, it, it)}

>>> print(d)
{'C53675': ('pass', 'pass'), 'C2456': ('fail', 'pass'), 'C01234': ('pass', 'pass')}
```

And this can be generalised to *n* values per key:

```
l = ['C01234', 'pass', 'pass', 'fail', 'C2456', 'fail', 'fail', 'pass', 'C53675', 'pass', 'pass', 'pass']
n = 3
d = {t[0]:t[1:] for t in zip(*[iter(l)]*(n+1))}

>>> print(d)
{'C53675': ('pass', 'pass', 'pass'), 'C2456': ('fail', 'fail', 'pass'), 'C01234': ('pass', 'pass', 'fail')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the slice operator (start:end:step) with a step of 3 to split the list up, for example:

```
l = ['C01234' , 'pass' , 'pass' , 'C2456' , 'fail' , 'pass' , 'C53675' , 'pass' , 'pass']

d = dict()

for key, val1, val2 in zip(l[::3], l[1::3], l[2::3]):
    d[key] = val1, val2
```

Answer (score 0):

If each entry has exactly two tests as in your first code block, slice it three times with a step of three, `zip()` it, and use it in a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k:[v1, v2] for k, v1, v2 in zip(sample[::3], sample[1::3], sample[2::3])}
```

Or if you don't know how many tests each entry will have, use an ordinary loop:

```
d = {}
results = {'pass', 'fail'}
for item in sample:
    if item not in results:
        d[item] = []
        current = item
    else:
        d[current].append(item)
```